# What other distributions provide the option to install inside Windows?

Tags: linux, fedora, windows, wubi

I mean installing with something like wubi? Can Fedora do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora cannot do that. Aside from Ubuntu, none of the distributions that I can recall can do that. The easiest way possible would be with a LiveUSB drive.

Comment: yes I agree with @Sicp that liveCD or liveUSB are good options to try a linux distro